# using a button instead of a checkbox to check all checkboxes in jquery

Tags: jquery

Currently using the following to select all checkboxes when a checkbox with id #checkall is checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#checkall').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
</script>
```

How can i change this to allow for the use of a button, instead of a checkbox?
Ive tried switching them out in the html, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: A sample of the HTML would be useful

Answer (score 2):

it's this bit here

```
attr('checked', this.checked);
```

a button does not have a `checked` attribute

Try using `element.data` to hold the value of the current checked status instead

for example, set `$('#checkall').data("checked","false")` on page initialization, and then on subsequent calls check what that value is, and switch it out for the opposite...

Comment: +1 - this would be better than using 'toggle' since the checkboxes could be unchecked without using the button.

Comment: Why use `data()` when you can simply store the `checked` value in a locally accessible variable?

Comment: I agree with J-P. data() is an overkill for this purpose

Comment: I dunno what the convention regarding .data() is, but as a simple rule of thumb, I use .data() to store any data pertaining to an element..  
Storing as a local var is fine, but what if you need the value of that particular var outside the scope of the function. In fact, I believe this is the optimal way without resorting to global variables...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're still using "this.checked", a button will never be checked. You'll have to use the 'toggle' feature instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem maybe in your

```
, this.checked
```

I.e. buttons don't have a checked status

Answer (score 0):

You still use this.checked in the `attr(...)` code which of course won't work as this is a button now and not a checkbox anymore. The following stores the current "checked" status in a data attribute on the button and thus allows you to toggle the checkboxes as before

```
$('#checkall').click(function () {
    var ele = $(this);
    var checked = ele.data("checked");
    checked = checked == undefined ? true : checked;
    $(this)
        .data("checked", !checked)
        .parents('fieldset:eq(0)')
        .find(':checkbox')
        .attr('checked', checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked = false;
var checkAll = $('#checkall');
var checkboxes = checkAll.parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox');

checkAll.click(function () {
    checkboxes.attr('checked', checked = !checked);
});
```

I've done two things:

- The current state of the checkboxes is stored in the `checked` variable.
- The checkboxes are not queried for on every click; instead we cache the collection and simply set the attribute when the `checkAll` button is clicked.

And, if you're worried about global variables, then just wrap it all in its own scope:

```
(function(){
    var checked = false;
    var checkAll = $('#checkall');
    var checkboxes = checkAll.parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox');

    checkAll.click(function () {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', checked = !checked);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each group a certain class, then do

```
$(".yourclass").attr("checked","true");
```